# Compare words in jquery between two div's and change the color of matched words

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have two div's contains sentences

**div1:**

```
 i have a pen in my pocket which is very costly.
```

**div2**

```
i have a  costly watch.
```

form the above given div's i want to compare the sentences to find and highlight the same  words which are present in both div's

Comment: What you have tried to get the output?

Comment: i have no idea to how to do this. give a suggestion for this

Comment: First step: write some code

Comment: If jQuery is required. I would get the values of the div's using .html(), turn them into an array and do the comparison.

Comment: can u give me the sample code that u tried

Comment: You can try reading the text inside the DIV then split the string making an array. Now loop through the array and find for a match. If there is a match wrap the word with a span tag having a class. Try writing some code and update your question.

Comment: It sounds like you want to split the two strings into words and then find their [longest common subsequence](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence), as in the Unix [diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility) utility. That's a classic dynamic programming problem, and you can find plenty of [material about it](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960229.html) if you [Google for it](https://www.google.com/search?q=longest+common+subsequence). Or you could just use [an existing library](https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small code that can help you kick-start and get the common words between two divs/lines:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var text1 = $('#div1').text();
  var text2 = $('#div2').text();

  var text1Words = text1.split(' ');
  var text2Words = text2.split(' ');

  var commonWords = $(text1Words).filter(text2Words).toArray();
  console.log(commonWords);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div1'>i have a pen in my pocket which is very costly.</div>

<div id='div2'>i have a costly watch.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1">
   i have a pen in my pocket which is very costly
</div>

<div id="div2">
   i have a costly watch
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var text1 = $('#div1').text().trim();
var text2 = $('#div2').text().trim();

var text1_arr = text1.split(' ');
var text1_temp = text1.split(' ');
var text2_arr = text2.split(' ');  

text1_arr.map(function(ele, index){
  if($.inArray( ele, text2_arr)!=-1){
    text1_arr[index] = '<b>'+ele+'</b>';
  }
});
text2_arr.map(function(ele, index){
  if($.inArray( ele, text1_temp)!=-1){
    text2_arr[index] = '<b>'+ele+'</b>';
  }
});

 $('#div1').html(text1_arr.join(' '));
 $('#div2').html(text2_arr.join(' '));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
<div id="div1">
    i have a pen in my pocket which is very costly
</div>

<div id="div2">
     i have a  costly watch
</div>

<div id= "final">
</div>
```

in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var div1 = $.trim($("#div1").text());
// alert(div1);
var divArray = div1.split(' ');
//alert(divArray);
var div2 = $.trim($("#div2").text());
var div2Array = div2.split(' ');

var html = '';
for(i = 0; i< div2Array.length; i++){
//alert(divArray[i]); //outputs individual numbers in array

var index = $.inArray( div2Array[i], divArray);

console.log(div2Array[i]);
if( index != -1 ) {
    html += "<b>"+div2Array[i]+"</b> ";
} else {
 html += div2Array[i] + " ";
}
}

console.log(html);
$("#final").html(html);
});
```

fiddle example

https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/21465/